# Http Gateways and Json Transformers: stripped headers

Tags: java, json, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration 4.0.3.RELEASE with Jackson2, I am trying to use Json Transformers in conjunction with http gateways.

My pathway looks akin to that of the amqp adapter referenced in the Spring Integration documentation but with http gateways(1):

> ...->object-to-json-transformer->http-outbound-gateway---->
>
> ---->http-inbound-gateway->json-to-object-transformer->

Client:

```
<int:chain id="messageTransformerChain" input-channel="toServer" output-channel="messagesToServer">
    ...
    <int:object-to-json-transformer />
</int:chain>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="httpOutToSever"
    request-channel="messagesToServer"
    reply-channel="replyFromServer"
    url="${server.endpoint}"
    http-method="POST"
    extract-request-payload="true"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" />
```

Server:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="httpInboundFromClientGateway"
    supported-methods="GET, POST"
    request-channel="fromClientChannel" />

<int:chain input-channel="fromClientChannel">
    <int:json-to-object-transformer />
    ...
</int:chain>
```

The exception I am getting is (what I think is relevant is in bold):

> 2014-08-22T23:58:21.640-0400 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-2]
>   o.s.i.h.i.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway failure occurred in
>   gateway sendAndReceive
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException:
>   failed to transform message   at
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:44)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:68)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:255)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:109)
>   ~[spring-messaging-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:144)
>   ~[spring-messaging-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:44)
>   ~[spring-messaging-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:75)
>   ~[spring-messaging-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:250)
>   [spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
>   [spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:473)
>   [spring-integration-http-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:370)
>   [spring-integration-http-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:101)
>   [spring-integration-http-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>   **[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]  Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve 'json__TypeId__'**
>   in 'javaTypes'.   at
>   org.springframework.integration.support.json.AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.createJavaType(AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.java:67)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.extractJavaType(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:119)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.support.json.Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.extractJavaType(Jackson2JsonObjectMapper.java:44)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.support.json.AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.fromJson(AbstractJacksonJsonObjectMapper.java:60)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.json.JsonToObjectTransformer.doTransform(JsonToObjectTransformer.java:81)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:33)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]   ... 102 common frames
>   omitted

When I debug, I see on the client side that the `json__TypeId__` header has been stripped from the outgoing message. When I add `JsonHeaders.HEADERS` to a `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` and inject the Gateways with this mapper, I see that when the mapper work is done, the Json headers ARE present, but when I end up back in `RestTemplate.doWithRequest` the `requestHeaders` no longer contain the Json ones. And of course, I get the same exception server side.

Perhaps my configurations are incorrect, but with that header being stripped I'm not sure how the server side would be able to do `json-to-object` transformation.

I would prefer not to explicitly indicate type on specific Mappers for channels since they can vary. Is there a way to configure the components I need to support this pathway?

-- References --

(1) http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#transformer Scroll to Json Transformers subsection

Answer (score 1):

With the outbound http adapter, user headers (in his case the json type information) are conveyed over HTTP as `X-<header>`...

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel" 
                           url="http://localhost:18080/http/receiveGateway"
                           http-method="POST"
                           mapped-request-headers="foo"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"/>

POST /http/receiveGateway HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/plain, */*
X-foo: bar
```

On the server side, the `X-` is not removed so you have to map it with the x...

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                      path="/receiveGateway"
                      mapped-request-headers="x-foo"
                      supported-methods="POST"/>
```

You will then need a `<header-enricher/>` in your `<chain/>` before the transformer to set the headers (minus the 'x-')...

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="json__TypeId__" expression="headers['x-json__TypeId__']" />
    ...
</int:header-enricher>
```

(Note lower case `x`).

EDIT:

Or, on the sending side, you can configure the mapper to NOT prefix the custom header(s)...

```
<bean id="mapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper">
    <property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="foo,bar" />
    <property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value="" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I had been trying the second way: adding the `JsonHeader.HEADERS` to the `DefaultHttpHeaderMapper` and setting the `userDefinedHeaderPrefix` ="". The `json__TypeId__` header still wasn't being mapped out. After more debugging I found out it's because the type for the value for this header is `java.lang.Class` and the `setHttpHeader` method does not know how to convert that since by default there is no `ConversionService` configured. So is it correct to create a Converter to convert the `java.lang.Class` value to a `String` for the header?

Comment: It might be cleaner to add a `header-enricher` after the transformer before the Gateway that sets this `json__TypeId__` header with a String type value.

Comment: One a different note, it seems common that `objectToJsonTransformer` and `jsonToObjectTransformer` are used together. The latter knows how to figure out the value for the `json__TypeId__` header from either a `java.lang.Class` or a `java.lang.String` but the former only supplies the `java.lang.Class` type. So it seems there is an asymmetry there.

Comment: Good point; please open an 'Improvement' [JIRA issue](jira.spring.io/browse/INT) - thanks.

Comment: @Gary Russell i faced same problem. and I think there is no header value in org.springframework.integration.mapping.support.JsonHeaders. So I can't transform message. I succeeded it with spring rest template.